# Provide me the Bit timing register calculation for FDCAN for Microchip.?

Tags: c

```
C1NBTCFGH = 0x001E;
C1NBTCFGL = 0x0707;
C1DBTCFGH = 0x000E;
C1DBTCFGL = 0x0303;
```

these values from reference manual. I need to understand how this values are got

Answer (score 0):

You need to be way more specific. Mention the part name and possibly attach the reference manual for the same in the comment, will help you out.

Comment: dspic33ck64mp508 https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/dsPIC33CK64MP508# the datasheet of respected controller